# How to get Web Socket URL from destination?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-cloud-platform

I am in need of a solution where I need to get the web socket URL in a secure way that is from the BTP Destinations. How can I add Web socket URL to destination and how can I call it from UI5 application (UI5 apps are neo based).

Thank you.

Comment: Where is your Websocket endpoint located? You are aware that the Neo HTML5 App repository doesn't support Websockets.

Comment: now i am directly using the wss url in the controller of ui5app. is there any way to access it from the destination as we use rest urls